# Conditional Expectation of XY When Individual Conditional Expectations Have a Certain Property

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Imagine we have $X$ and $Y$ defined on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ such that $\mathbb{E}|X|, \mathbb{E}|Y|, \mathbb{E}|XY| < \infty$.  Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be be $\sigma$-fields such that $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{F}$.

Assume that $X$ has the property that $\mathbb{E}(X| \: \mathcal{B}) = \mathbb{E}(X| \: \mathcal{A})$ and $Y$ has the property that $\mathbb{E}(Y| \: \mathcal{B}) = \mathbb{E}(X| \: \mathcal{A})$

Must it be the case that $\mathbb{E}(XY| \: \mathcal{B}) = \mathbb{E}(XY| \: \mathcal{A})$?

I cannot find a simple counterexample but I cannot prove it either. I have tried to derive it when $X$ and $Y$ are indicator functions and playing around with the tower property.  If it is not true, is there a situation where it could be true (i.e. $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative, $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are countable,...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}) = ([0,1),\mathcal{B}([0,1]),\mu)$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the trivial sigma algebra, and $\mathcal{B} = \sigma([0,1/2),[1/2,1))$.

Define,

\begin{align*}
X(\omega) &= \begin{cases}
4\omega &\text{ if } \omega \in [0,1/2)\\
4\omega - 2 &\text{ if } \omega \in [1/2,1)
\end{cases}\\
Y(\omega) &= \begin{cases}
1 &\text{ if } \omega \in [0,1/2)\\
4\omega-2 &\text{ if } \omega \in [1/2,1)
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Then for all $\omega\in \Omega$,

$$\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{A})(\omega) = \mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{B})(\omega) = \mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{A})(\omega) = \mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{B})(\omega) = 1.$$

For all $\omega\in\Omega$,

$$\mathbb{E}(XY|\mathcal{A})(\omega) = \mathbb{E}(XY) = 1/2 + 2/3 = 7/6.$$

But,

$$\mathbb{E}(XY|\mathcal{B})(\omega) = \begin{cases}
1 &\text{ if } \omega \in [0,1/2)\\
4/3 &\text{ if } \omega \in [1/2,1)
\end{cases}.$$

So $\mathbb{E}(XY|\mathcal{A})\neq\mathbb{E}(XY|\mathcal{B})(\omega).$

Intuition: $\mathcal{A}$ is more coarse than $\mathcal{B}$, so its easiest to look for understanding or counterexamples in simple finite sigma algebras like I presented above. All we need are $X$ and $Y$ that have a constant average on every set in $\mathcal{B}$, but that achieve that average in different ways on different sets of $\mathcal{B}$. Then that average is no longer preserved when $X$ and $Y$ are multiplied together, so $XY$ has different averages on different sets in $B$. This ensures that $\mathbb{E}(XY|\mathcal{B})$ is not $\mathcal{A}$-measurable. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I realize now that this could be simplified a lot. A nicer counterexample might have $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\},\mathcal{B} = \sigma(\{1,2\},\{3,4\})$ and $\mathcal{A}$ is the trivial sigma algebra. Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the uniform distribution. Let $X(1)=0,X(2)=2,X(3)=0,X(4)=2$. Let $Y(1)=2,Y(2)=0,Y(3)=1,Y(4)=1$. The computations would be much simpler and more intuitive, but it's the exact same idea as what I presented above.